# Is there a way to test out what my site will behave and look like on a mobile device by using a desktop browser?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, ios, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulators/emulators for mobile browser testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing)

I would like to see how my site looks like and behaves when viewed on a mobile device like an **iPhone**, **iPad**, **Android**, etc. The problem is that I don't own any of these devices. 
Specifically I want to see how it would be to use touch on the site. Recently a friend of mine looked at my site on his iPhone and told me that he had to touch the home link twice:

1. to play the jQuery animation that was attached to the home link
2. to get to home

Is there a way (via **web app** or **JS/jQuery code**) I can emulate the environments of these different mobile device browsers so I can get a good idea of how my site behaves and looks in them?

Comment: This question has been asked a few times on Stack Overflow. For example: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing"

Comment: Use jquery mobile or the sencha library, and you can get the functionality the other browsers provide.

Comment: @Jason thanks. i will flag it as being a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for iPhone and iPad web browser testing, if you own an Intel Mac running Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6.x), you can sign up at developer.apple.com and download and install the free iOS SDK.  Included in the SDK download is an iPhone Simulator, which includes a simulated Mobile Safari for iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 1):

According to various luminaries of the web development world, the only way to test your site/app on a mobile platform is to **test your app on the mobile platform.** Even the proprietary emulators are (reputed to be) inadequate.

I'm specifically thinking about Mr. Resig and all the stuff he's written/talked about with respect to the mobile web. Between iOS, the various Android versions/phones, Blackberry, and etc., the variety is so great that you really have no choice but to test on everything.